# Bootstrap 4 scroll to div

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4

Im using Bootstrap 4 and for some reason the scroll to div function is only working on mobile phone/smaller screen sizes.

Javascript code:

```
  <script>
    $(".navbar-nav li a").click(function(event) {
        if (!$(this).parent().hasClass('dropdown'))
            $(".navbar-collapse").collapse('hide');
    });   </script>
```

Navbar link:

```
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#about-us"><button type="button" class="btn btn-green">About</button></a>
        </li>
```

Div:

```
  <div class="about" id="about-us">
    <div class="container">
      test
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`navbar-brand` class is overlapping the `navbar-nav`.So add z-index to the `navbar-nav` in your html page i.e

```
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto" style="z-index:1;">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add following to your css file:

```
.navbar-brand.mx-auto {
  width: 216px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```